# How to use pipe within -exec in find

Tags: unix, find, exec, pipe

Is there any way to use pipe within an -exec in find? I don't want grep to go through whole file, but only through first line of each file.

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -print -exec grep yourstring {} \;
```

I tried to put the pipelines there with "cat" and "head -1", but it didn't work very well. I tried to use parenthesis somehow, but I didn't manage to work out how exactly to put them there.
I would be very thankful for your help. I know how to work it out other way, without using the find, but we tried to do it in school with the usage of find and pipeline, but couldn`t manage how to.

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -print -exec cat {} | head -1 | grep yourstring \;
```

This is somehow how we tried to do it, but could't manage the parenthesis and wheter it is even possible. I tried to look through net, but couldn' t find any answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to unix.stackexchange.com and has an answer there at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42407/pipe-find-into-grep-v

Comment: Another answer (for grepping) is there http://serverfault.com/questions/9822/recursive-text-search-with-grep-and-file-patterns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a pipe in the exec parameter for a find command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62044/how-do-i-use-a-pipe-in-the-exec-parameter-for-a-find-command)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In order to be able to use a pipe, you need to execute a *shell* command, i.e. the command with the pipeline has to be a single command for `-exec`.

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -print -exec sh -c "cat {} | head -1 | grep yourstring" \;
```

Note that the above is a *Useless Use of Cat*, that could be written as:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -print -exec sh -c "head -1 {} | grep yourstring" \;
```

---

Another way to achieve what you want would be to say:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -print -exec awk 'NR==1 && /yourstring/' {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

This does not directly answer your question, but if you want to do some complex operations you might be better off scripting:

`for file in $(find /path/to/dir -type f); do echo ${file}; cat $file | head -1 | grep yourstring; done`

Comment: A loop through file names with white spaces in "find" will give some problems. Here you have a post with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Yes, this will not work for files that contain spaces, it will also split those filenames up. I like this approach (using a for loop), since it's clearer to read. But this has some issues. lamanux's link is good