# bash find with two commands in an exec ~ How to find a specific Java class within a set of JARs

Tags: jar, find, exec

My use case is I want to search a collection of JARs for a specific class file. More specifically, I want to search recursively within a directory for all *.jar files, then list their contents, looking for a specific class file.

So this is what I have so far:

```
find . -name *.jar -type f -exec echo {} \; -exec jar tf {} \;
```

This will list the contents of all JAR files found recursively. I want to put a `grep` *within* the seconed `exec` because I want the second `exec` to only print the contents of the JAR that `grep` matches.

If I just put a pipe and pipe it all to grep afterward, like:

```
find . -name *.jar -type f -exec echo {} \; -exec jar tf {} \; | grep $CLASSNAME
```

Then I lose the output of the first `exec`, which tells me where the class file is (the name of JAR file is likely to not match the class file name).

So if there was a way for the `exec` to run two commands, like:

```
-exec "jar tf {} | grep $CLASSNAME" \;
```

Then this would work. Using a `grep $(...)` in the `exec` command wouldn't work because I need the `{}` from the `find` to take the place of the file that was found.

Is this possible?
(*Also I am open to other ways of doing this, but the command line is preferred.*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - still using "one" command. What I was looking for was actually answered in the question [How to use pipe within -exec in find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21825690/1733377). What I have to do is use a *shell* command with my `exec`. This ends up making the command look like:

```
 find . -name *.jar -type f -exec echo {} \; -exec sh -c "jar tf {} | grep --color $CLASSNAME" \;
```

The `--color` will help the final result to stick out while the command is recursively listing all JAR files.

A couple points:

- This assumes I have a `$CLASSNAME` set. The class name has to appear as it would in a JAR, not within a Java package. So `com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject` would become `com/ibm/json/java/JSONObject.class`.
- This requires a JDK - that is where we get the `jar` command. The JDK must be accessible on the system path. If you have a JDK that is not on the system path, you can set an environment variable, such as `JAR` to point to the `jar` executable. I am running this from cygwin, so it turns out my `jar` installation is within the "Program Files" directory. The presence of a space breaks this, so I have to add these two commands:

  ```
  export JAR=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/jar
  find . -name *.jar -type f -exec echo {} \; -exec sh -c "\"$JAR\" tf {} | grep --color $CLASSNAME" \;
  ```

  The `$JAR` in the shell command must be escaped otherwise the terminal will not know what to do with the space in "Program Files".

Answer (score 0):

i find it difficult to execute multiple commands within find-exec, so i usually only grab the results with find and loop around the results.

maybe something like this might help?

`find . -type f -name *.jar | while read jarfile; do echo $jarfile; jar tf $jarfile; done`