# Bash : Piping Find into Grep

Tags: bash, grep, find

The following command finds all occurrences of 'some string' by recursively searching through the current directory and all sub-directories

```
grep -r -n  'some string' .
```

This command recursively searches through current directory and all sub-directories and returns all files of the form *.axvw

```
find . -name '*.axvw'
```

I want to put these two commands together so I get all occurances of 'some string' by recursively searching through the current directory but only looking at files that end in 'axvw'.

When I tried running the following command nothing was returned:

```
find . -name '*js' | grep -n  'some string'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See the answers given here: http://serverfault.com/questions/9822/recursive-text-search-with-grep-and-file-patterns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use pipe within -exec in find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825393/how-to-use-pipe-within-exec-in-find)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `-exec` option in `find`:

```
find . -name '*.axvw' -exec grep -n 'some string' {} +
```

Or else use `xargs`:

```
find . -name '*.axvw' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -n 'some string'
```

Comment: `-exec grep -n 'some string' {} +` would make the `find -exec` approach competitive with xargs on performance, and is guaranteed to be available by the 2006 POSIX spec.

Answer (score 2):

`find . -name '*js' -exec grep -n 'some string' {} \;`

Should work I think.

Edit: just for fun, you could also use a double grep I believe.

`find . | grep 'some string' | grep js`

Comment: No, the "double grep" you suggest does not help -- it's grepping the filenames, not contents, in both stages.