# Mysql Restore from many dump files

Tags: mysql, restore, database-restore, mysql-backup

We have an regular backup system which backs up every table from the DB into a separate files.

Like a table named

> fo

will be dumped and compressed into a

> foo.sql.bz2

I googled this kind of compresion and all i could think of to get it but i am out of ideas.

Anyone knows which tool is making backups like this and how can i restore the whole DB from milions of thouse files?

ps. We have over 700 tables, so resoring one by one is... kinda inpractical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.bz2` extension usually denotes a [BZ2-compressed archive](http://www.bzip.org/1.0.5/bzip2.txt).

[To decompress](https://superuser.com/a/480951/201505):

```
bzip2 -d foo.sql.bz2 # produces file "foo.sql"
```

[Combine with `find`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62060/1446005), and the magic happens:

```
find /path/to/dump/directory -name "*.sql.bz2" | xargs bzip2 -cd {} | mysql [options]
```

Comment: Just wanted to thank you again for it, you rock dude!!!! :D would kiss you if i could :D

Comment: Ahem, please, don't (not in public;)