# How to use >> inside find -exec statement?

Tags: bash, shell, find

From time to time I have to append some text at the end of a bunch of files. I would normally find these files with `find`.

I've tried

```
find . -type f -name "test" -exec tail -n 2 /source.txt >> {} \;
```

This however results in writing the last two lines from `/source.txt` to a file named `{}` however many times a file was found matching the search criteria.

I guess I have to escape `>>` somehow but so far I wasn't successful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `-exec bash -c 'tail -n 2 /source.txt >> "$1"' bash {} \;`. Also, I haven't tested it, but storing the output of `tail -n 2` in some environment variable and writing that would probably be faster if you're worried about performance (could also play around with `+` and `tee` variants)

Comment: I'd just pipe into  xargs instead

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62044/how-do-i-use-a-pipe-in-the-exec-parameter-for-a-find-command), but not exactly sure if that's considered a duplicate so switching my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-exec` only takes one command (with optional arguments) and you can't use any bash operators in it.

So you need to wrap it in a `bash -c '...'` block, which executes everything between `'...'` in a new bash shell.

```
find . -type f -name "test" -exec bash -c 'tail -n 2 /source.txt >> "$1"' bash {} \;
```

*Note: Everything after `'...'` is passed as regular arguments, except they start at $0 instead of $1. So the `bash` after `'` is used as a placeholder to match how you would expect arguments and error processing to work in a regular shell, i.e. $1 is the first argument and errors generally start with `bash` or something meaningful*

If execution time is an issue, consider doing something like `export variable="$(tail -n 2 /source.txt)"` and using `"$variable"` in the `-exec`. This will also always write the same  thing, unlike using `tail` in `-exec`, which could change if the file changes. Alternatively, you can use something like `-exec ... +` and pair it with `tee` to write to many files at once.

Comment: It works! Thanks for the solution and explanation. It's usually not too many files but if that changes I'll come back to your comments.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient alternative (assuming `bash` 4):

```
shopt -s globstar
to_augment=( **/test )
tail -n 2 /source.txt | tee -a "${to_augment[@]}" > /dev/null
```

First, you create an array with all the file names, using a simple pattern that should be equivalent to your call to `find`. Then, use `tee` to append the desired lines to all those files at once.

If you have more criteria for the `find` command, you can still use it; this version is not foolproof, as it assumes no filename contains a newline, but fixing that is best left to another question.

```
while read -r fname; do
    to_augment+=( "$fname" )
done < <(find ...)
```